# Xcode Discarded All Changes without commiting

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally hit discard all changes without having "committed". It seems to have wiped all the info from the app when I open Xcode but when I go to the project file all the .swift files and icons are still there. I have tried what the other posts have said about all of the git commands but this seems to be different. Since discarding changes brought me to the starting part of the project but I still have all the files from before is there an alternative way I can restore my program?

Comment: You LOST it man, since the changes were not committed, sorry, you need to RECODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just re-add the files in Xcode?

`Xcode > File > Add files to`...

... and reselect the .swift files / icons that you mentioned that are still there.

Comment: Yes I managed to do that but unfortunately the main.storyboard was overwritten and I have to restart it :(

Comment: That's way I prefer using Git via CLI. :-) If the above answers the question, please mark it as accepted.